# C# Anonymous method variable scope problem with IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, generics, scope, anonymous-methods

I'm trying to iterate through all components and for those who implements ISupportsOpen allow to open a project.
The problem is when the anonymous method is called, then the component variable is always the same element (as coming from the outer scope from IEnumerable)

```
foreach (ISupportsOpen component in something.Site.Container.Components.OfType<ISupportsOpen>())
{
    MyClass m = new MyClass();  
    m.Called += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                           
        if (component.CanOpenProject(..)) component.OpenProject(..);
    });

    itemsList.Add(m);
}
```

How should it be solved, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just don't [close over the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) - copy it:

```
foreach (ISupportsOpen component in 
         something.Site.Container.Components.OfType<ISupportsOpen>())
{
    ISupportsOpen copy = component;
    MyClass m = new MyClass();  
    m.Called += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {                           
        if (copy.CanOpenProject(..)) copy.OpenProject(..);
    });

    itemsList.Add(m);
}
```

This way you get a new "instance" of the `copy` variable for each iteration of the loop - so each delegate will capture that different instance. Before, every delegate was capturing the same variable.

(This is in some ways a duplicate question, but it's the kind of problem which is relatively hard to search for, so I'm happy to answer it many times.)

Comment: I'm just curious, why doesn't the run-time hold that instance in memory when he knows that the instance is being used? Why was the delegate before capturing the same variable ?

Comment: @PaN1C_Showt1Me: The language specification defines `foreach` in terms of a single variable; that variable is captured, so it's all working according to the spec. (It's a language thing rather than a run-time thing.) See Eric's blog post (linked) for further details. I'm sure if the language designers had a time machine, they'd change the behaviour of foreach - but it's too late now.